# tabindex doesn't work with input disabled

Tags: angular, primeng, wai-aria, tabindex

When Input is disabled screen reader doesn't read the input.

```
     <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="state" [disabled]="true"" [attr.tabindex]="0" />
```

I don't know why s`tabindex=0` doesn't work if input is disabled, because if I the input is not disabled , it works. Anyone can help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using the one-way [data-binding syntax](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax). In your case, you should just declare the `tabindex` attribute normally without the square brackets:

```html
<input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="state" disabled tabindex="0" />
```

Sidenote: You should also remove the data-binding for the [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) attribute: since you're already assigning it to a value of `true`, you might as well just declare it as you normally would - without any value.